# javascript - help me understand this structure (lexical scoping)

Tags: javascript, function

Below is simplification of some code I am trying to understand.

What are we trying to do in this javascript fragment? It seems we are creating object(?) called `myCompany` if not already created, then adding child object `myProject` to `myCompany`.
Then creating a local variable within`myCompany.myProject` and another local to function  `myCompany.myProject.myfunction`. The `()` at the end make it execute immediately. And we are doing this to keep `localVariable_1` out of global space?

```
var myCompany= myCompany || {};   
if (!myCompany.myProject) {
    myCompany.myProject = {};
}

myCompany.myProject = function () {

    var localVariable_1;

    function myFunction(){
        var anotherlocalVariable;
        // .. do some stuff
    }

}();
```

Comment: This essentially does nothing. Everything being done to `myProject` here is pretty pointless. The immediately invoked anonymous function at the end returns nothing, so `myProject` is nothing.

Comment: Agreed. The entire code can be replaced with `// do bugger all` and it would have the exact same effective result.

Comment: Untrue. It defines "myCompany" object (if not already defined). And defines a property "myProject" of that with `undefined` value. The entire code can be replaced with `var myCompany = {myProject: undefined};`

Comment: @JoelCox they're talking about the immediate function assigned to `myCompany.myProject` that function has no side effects so it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: The op wrote that this is simplified code. He just wants to understand the structure.

Comment: @Mouser Then the code is simplified beyond usefulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line checks if the object exists, if not use shorthand definition `{}` to create an Object. `||` compares. If argument one is null set argument two.

The if on the next line checks if the property myProject isn't set on the object. `!` is the operator. If myCompany.myProject returns undefined this if clause returns true. When true create object as property myProject.

Third part: myProject gets replaced by a function object. This function is defined between { and }, but is immediately called upon by the `()` behind the function declaration.

localvariable_1 will never be in the global scope since it has the `var` statement. Binding it to the scope of myCompany.myProject function. Maybe this function is directly called to set up some initial values, but wrap them in a function that could be reused to change the values at another moment.

Comment: thanks, I seem to be on right track, even if example "does sweet buqqer all" :)

Answer (score 1):

One piece at a time...

```
var myCompany= myCompany || {};
```

if `myCompany` exists you set it to it, otherwise you create an empty object and set myCompany to an empty object.

*NOTE: if `myCompany` already exists you have no indicator of what it is*

```
if (!myCompany.myProject) {
    myCompany.myProject = {};
}
```

Now that you know myCompany is an object you verify it has a `project` property on it. if not you set `myProject` to an empty object.

*NOTE: you have tested nothing about `myProject` so again there is no indicator of what it is*

```
myCompany.myProject = function () {
  var localVariable_1;
  function myFunction(){
    var anotherlocalVariable;
    // .. do some stuff
  }
}();
```

Here you are assigning `myCompany.myProject`.  Notice at the bottom the `()` before the `;`  That makes this function get executed immediately.  Inside of the function you are creating another function that currently isn't doing anything.  Where you aren't returning from the function I think it will set `myProject` to undefined.

You may already know what an immediate function is but if not it is basically a function that is called right away. It is also standard to wrap it in a `()` so that it is easier to read for example

```
var someFunction = (function () { 
    /*whatever*/
} ());
```

You said this was simplified from the original so I am guessing you removed an important part of the code that actually does things but the confusion is probably due to the JavaScript's way of scoping.  It uses what is called Lexical scoping.  You can think of it as scoping by functions.

Another thing that may be tripping you up is how JavaScript uses **truthy** evaluation for logical comparisons.

The last thing to mention that might be confusing the way you read the code is javascript's hoisting.

Hopefully that helps or at least points you to a few things you can look into to figure out the parts you don't exactly understand.

Comment: realize that the example is a bit lame, but is this good pattern to limit poluting global space?

Comment: It's a way to do it, it depends on where you are doing things.

If it is in Node (on the backend) then you would want to use node modules, if it is the browser on the front end I have seen similar patterns to help your abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I just hate writing in comments lol.

If you are trying to help prevent your global scope from getting polluted then you might want to use objects and a something similar to what you are doing.  Depending on how crazy you want to get you could look into **Prototypical Inheritance**.

A common pattern is to do something like this

```
var company = (function() {
  var name;

  var getName = function() { 
    return name;
  };

  var setName = function(n) { 
    name = n;
  };

  return {
    getName : getName,
    setName : setName
  }
}())
```

Now you can do `company.setName("yoda")` or whatever.

This will give you a basic getter and setter where no one can change the companies name without going through your getter and setter and it also doesn't pollute the global scope.  You can have whatever you want on company this way and you also encapsulate the data within the object.

Notice how `var company =` a function that is called immediately which returns an object that has whatever you want to encapsulate on it.

Is that what you are talking about?